# Are there infinitely many primes whose factorials have palindromic numbers of digits (and an additional property)?

Tags: number-theory, palindrome

Let be $p_n$ a prime. Let $s\#$ denote the product of all primes up to $s$.

> I ask for primes $p_n$ such that $p_n!$ has a number of digits which is a palindromic number and such that $n\#$ has as well a number of digits which is a palindromic number.
>
> I found this example:
>
> - $p_{1036}!=8263!$ has 28782 digits, which is a palindromic number; and $1036\#$ has 434 digits, which is as well a palindromic number.

Are there other primes $p$ of this type? Do you believe that they are infinitely many? Somebody could write a routine for finding solutions?

Comment: We don't need to check to know this is open. (Whether there is an infinite amount)

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo what do you mean?

Comment: This is unsolvable

Comment: yes but there are other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

The following are the primes under $10^8$ that work:

$\begin{pmatrix}
p_n & n &  \text{digits in }p_n! &  \text{digits in }n\# \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
5 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\ 
7 & 4 & 4 & 1 \\ 
11 & 5 & 8 & 2 \\ 
37 & 12 & 44 & 4 \\ 
1777 & 275 & 5005 & 111 \\ 
8263 & 1036 & 28782 & 434 \\ 
10477 & 1282 & 37573 & 535 \\ 
12641 & 1510 & 46364 & 636 \\ 
19469 & 2208 & 75057 & 929 \\ 
340601 & 29231 & 1736371 & 12621 \\ 
681727 & 55195 & 3680863 & 23832 \\
\end{pmatrix}$